# How can I change a string to integer to use in a for loop

Tags: c#

I have been doing C++ but recently I started doing a bit more on C# Windows Form Application and I'm making a program where you input a number and it flips a coin that amount of times. This is my code so far:

```
    private void flipCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String HorT;
        int randomizer;
        for (int i = 0; i <= int.Parse(flipCoin.Text); i++)
        {
            randomizer = rnd.Next(1, 2);
            if (randomizer == 1)
            {
            HorT = "Heads";
            }
            else
            {
            HorT = "Tails";
            }
            richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + HorT);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem? Please explain

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= int.Parse(flipCoin.Text); i++) gives an error of:           An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.                                                                                                       I'm really new and don't really know what that means

Comment: make sure flipcoin.text is not null

Comment: If you have more information, you should edit the question, not put it all into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code.

First, if your user types something that is not an integer number (or doesn't type anything at all) then Parse call will throw an exception and it is best practice avoid the exception if you can.

Second, the for loop, loops on time too much, you start from zero and stops at the limit less 1

So you could change your code to

```
private void flipCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String HorT;
    int randomizer;
    int count;

    // Int32.TryParse return false if the input is not an integer
    if(!Int32.TryParse(flipCoin.Text, out count))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Please type an integer number");
         return;
    }

    // Loop until the indexer is less than the limit       
    for (int i = 0; i < count); i++)
    {
         ....
```

**EDIT**
Just noticed another problem in this line

```
   randomizer = rnd.Next(1,2);
```

as MSDN says the parameters for the Next call are the minValue and the maxValue, but maxValue should be

> The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must
>   be greater than or equal to minValue.

So if you want random numbers between 1 and 2 **included** you should write

```
   randomizer = rnd.Next(1,3);
```

Comment: This seems to work quite well apart from the fact that when you type in an integer number it says "Please type an integer number" so it never displays results :P

Comment: Did you put the operator ! in front of the method call Int32.TryParse?

Comment: Yeah, and without it it doesn't give the non an integer message but it doesn't do anything

Comment: This is very strange. Int32.TryParse is the correct way to handle numeric integer input and it never failed for me. What did you type in the input box? Could you put a breakpoint on the TryParse line and check what's happening in the click event?

Comment: Another question, do you have a textbox named flipCoin not a button with that name right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to work with the string. I would take a bool. Take the input string and convert it as soon as possible to bool like:

```
bool HorT = false;
if (input=="Head") HorT =true;
```

Then write a boolean Flip function:

```
bool Flip(bool value) ...
```

And then put the result back as string:

```
string output = "Head";
if (HorT==true) output ="Tail";
```

This keeps your logic separate from input and output and avoids this kind of problems even if calculations increase.